# Numpy Arrays and Gtk ListStores

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, gtk3

I'd like to discuss some general decisions I have to make for my little project. It's mostly concerning the memory consumption, but also data integrity.

It is an accounting tool, having a list of records and calculate some financial figures, as print the accounts, calculate sums on monthly/quarterly basis, balance sheet etc... For the GUI I use GTK, because of license reasons, it is more free than QT, but both are available under Windows and MAC as well.

My general approach is to store the list of records in a 2dimensional numpy array. To show an account in particular I just need to create a view, which shares the memory with the original array. So, it is fast and ain't memory hungry.

But to show data in GTK3 I need a ListStore. So my questions are:

1. To copy the data from the numpy array to the ListStore would
   multiply my memory use?
2. If I display the data tables "editable", I have to manage an
   automatic synchronisation between the ListStore and the numpy array?
3. Is there any other, more elegant approach to avoid having two tables (array and ListStore)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if it's possible with the Python GTK bindings, but [`GtkListStore`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/ListStore.html#Gtk.ListStore) is an implementation of the [`GtkTreeModel`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/interfaces/TreeModel.html#Gtk.TreeModel) interface.

You may be able to create an object which proxies your NumPy array as a `GtkTreeModel` by implementing its [virtual methods](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/interfaces/TreeModel.html#virtual-methods). E.g.:

```
class MyListStore(object):
    def __init__(self, ndarray):
        self._ndarray = ndarray

    def do_get_column_type(self, index_):
        ...
```

Synchronizing is a bit more tricky if you want to make the tables editable. At least, synchronizing from the array to the tree model is easy; if you emit the `row-changed` signal when your ndarray changes programmatically, then the changes will automatically show up in your UI. The other way around will have to be more manual.